# Consulta sobre actualizacion de estado con useEffect React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[image: useEffect React]
El console.log en la linea 27 me da bien la informacion, pero tengo un probllema a la hora de actualizar el estado en la linea 26

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema? recuerda que siempre es mejor [agregar el código en formato de texto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Envolve la funcion map asi: ``await Promise.all( itemsData.results.map... )`` y listo.

Comment: Gracias por la recomendacion g.4 y me sirvio la solucion Agustin G, muchas gracias

Comment: @WSenjuW listo ahi la agregue como respuesta, y deje un link a un articulo por si queres saber porque sucede esto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu solucion es envolver el map en una promesa de la siguiente manera:

```
await Promise.all( 
      itemsData.result.map(...
)
```

Y setear el estado luego de cerrado el `Promise`

> podria intentar explicarte el porqué pero este articulo es mejor que cualquier explicacion mia: https://midu.dev/como-usar-async-await-con-array-prototype-map/